# Guidance on how to handle background and foreground core data with UI responsiveness

Tags: ios, core-data

So I've been playing with this "issue" for a long time here and I keep getting into issues:

Here is more or less what I would like for my dataflow

- User Segues to Controller
- Controller pings FTP site (if up continue)
- Loop through each parent record
- Parse each record (this is a slow process) turning it and all sub data into a giant JSON structure which is stored in a temp directory

  - Update the Screen to the user with the progress of the parsing task
- Upload the JSON Structure via FTP
- Once successfully uploaded update the "isUploaded" field on the record

Now where I've go into all sort of issues is with keeping the UI updated.  I'm designing a somewhat simple UI where we have a status bar that shows the process of each JSON file parsing task.  I can make things work but once I' try to get a nice responsive UI i've run into all sorts of issues.

I understand I'm supposed to do CoreData on the main thread, but, in doing so my UI doesn't update and becomes unresponsive.

I segue a `NSManagedObjectContext` over to this controller and I understand from that objectContext I can likely reference the `NSPersistantStoreCoordiantor` and create a second `NSManagedObjectContext` for a second threat and somehow I can likely synchronize these threads.

I've gotten things into a mess with `performSelectorOnMainThread` and `performSelectorInBackground` calls  all over the place etc.

Either I get things working the way I'd like or I get some sort of error with my managedObjectContext's and I'm thinking perhaps its time for a little rewrite instead of trying to salvage what I have.

Can somebody point me to some ideas about what i should use?  I can't seem to exactly wrap my head correctly around the multithreaded core-data concepts as to whether I'm supposed to use `NSOperationQueues` GCD or some other way of doing things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreData has the ability to operate in a multithreaded environment, as long as you keep managed objects and contexts bound to their proper thread/queue.

To scrape the surface see [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html)

You can create a background context by initialising it as a "private queue" bound context (see [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/initWithConcurrencyType%3a) for more details).

Basically, this would mean that in order to use this context properly you have to execute code on it wrapped in the contexts `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` methods.
you can use these methods to queue "tasks" for the context to execute (serial execution queue).
this code will be executed in the background.

You could also create a context that is confined to a specific thread (`NSConfinementConcurrencyType`) and then only access it in the thread it was created in without the use of the "perform block" methods.

merging the changes in this context to your main context is done by either setting the main context as a parent for the context after initialisation, or by registering to its "did save" notification and merging the changes to the main context (the first method is easier to implement).

One solution to your flow would be:

1. Create a main queue context (to be passes around to all view controllers)
2. Create an operation queue
3. observe a status entity (fetched in the main context) in your view (directly or by using a [FRC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html))
4. each operation would create a "private queue" context with the main context as parent
5. when updates are ready to be committed (including status updates), save the private context and the main context using `performBlockAndWait:` (just to keep the operation coherent)

This will still affect your main thread if there are many updates as all saves will go through the main context.
Try to segment your saves to avoid locking the main context for too long.